# Converting an ASP function to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, code-conversion

I'm in the process of moving a recording studio website from a windows based server to a linux one. It's all html and php except one page that uses an ASP function to update new releases.
I've been trying to convert it myself using "echo", but I couldn't get even close to a working code.
Here it is:

```
<%

Function PrintRecord(strImage, strAutore, strTitolo, strInfo, strCredits)
    dim strRet
    strRet = strRet + " <td valign=""top"">"
    strRet = strRet + " <div style=""margin-left: 20px""> "
    strRet = strRet + "     <img src=""pictures_works/" + strImage + """ height=""80"" width=""80"" border=""1"">"
    strRet = strRet +"  </td>"
    strRet = strRet + " <td width=""170px"" valign=""top"">"
    strRet = strRet + "     <font class=""TestoPiccoloNo"">"
    strRet = strRet + "         <b>" + strAutore + "</b><br>"
    strRet = strRet + "         " + strTitolo + "<br>"
    strRet = strRet + "         " + strInfo + "<br>"
    strRet = strRet + "<i>- " + strCredits + " </i>"
    strRet = strRet + "     </font>"
    strRet = strRet + " </div> "
    strRet = strRet + " </td>"
    PrintRecord = strRet
End Function

%>
```

And here's the code I use to update:

```
<%=PrintRecord("somepic.jpg","someband","somerecord","somelabel","whodidwhat")%>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You made me travel 10 years to the past.

Comment: It's exactly when the site was made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can do multilines string.

```
<?php

function PrintRecord($strImage, $strAutore, $strTitolo, $strInfo, $strCredits){
  $strRet = '
    <td valign="top">
      <div style="margin-left: 20px">
      <img src="pictures_works/'.$strImage.'" height="80" width="80" border="1">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="170px" valign="top">
     <div>
       <font class="TestoPiccoloNo">
          <b>'.$strAutore.'</b><br>
          '.$strTitolo.'<br>
          '.$strInfo.'<br>
          <i>- '.$strCredits.'</i>
       </font>
    </div>
   </td>';
  return $strRet;
}
?>
```

or by HEREDOC Syntax :

```
<?php
function PrintRecord($strImage, $strAutore, $strTitolo, $strInfo, $strCredits){
    $strRet = << EOT
    <td valign="top">
      <div style="margin-left: 20px">
      <img src="pictures_works/{$strImage}" height="80" width="80" border="1">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="170px" valign="top">
     <div>
       <font class="TestoPiccoloNo">
          <b>{$strAutore}</b><br>
          {$strTitolo}<br>
          {$strInfo}<br>
          <i>- {$strCredits}</i>
       </font>
    </div>
   </td>
   EOT;
  return $strRet;
}
?>
```

and use it like this :

```
<?php echo PrintRecord("somepic.jpg","someband","somerecord","somelabel","whodidwhat");?>
```

Well, how do it looks ?

Comment: Would be even more convenient with [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: @syck : yes, it can be

Comment: You are missing an `echo` or `<?=`

Comment: works perfectly! you just missed a `{` after at the end of the first line

Answer (score 2):

- replace every `+` with a `.`
- prefix variables with `$`
- terminate lines with `;`
- `$strRet = $strRet .` can be shortened to `$strRet .=`
- adapt opening and closing tags
- enclose function with curly brackets
- replace `""` with `\"`

---

```
<?php

function PrintRecord($strImage, $strAutore, $strTitolo, $strInfo, $strCredits) {
    $strRet = '';
    $strRet .= " <td valign=\"top\">";
    $strRet .= " <div style=\"margin-left: 20px\"> ";
    // :
    // ...similar
    // :
    $strRet .= "         <b>" . $strAutore . "</b><br>"; // example for concatenation
    // :
    $strRet .= " </div> ";
    $strRet .= " </td>";
    return $strRet;
}

?>
```

and

```
<?php echo PrintRecord("somepic.jpg","someband","somerecord","somelabel","whodidwhat"); ?>
```

Comment: You forgot a `$` sign at `strAutore`

Comment: Thank you, corrected. I was kept by fighting against the formatting problems.

Comment: Got it working with a few syntax changes to your code. Html tags need to be between "'" Shall I edit your answer? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to (and if it is possible), no objection. But I think the more important part is the list of changes above.